# How to consume the web service in window phone 7 application?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, windows-phone-7, wcf

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to window phone 7 application. I am developing asp.net web service application in .net framework 3.5 for my wp7 application. I have written some function in this web service. Now I am trying to consume this web service by right clicking on the project name & selecting the 'Add Service Reference' then I clicked on the 'Advance' button. After clicking on the advance button I can see that the 'Add Web Reference' button is disabled. I am not able to enable it. Can you please tell me why this is happening ? Can we consume the asp.net web service application of .net framework 3.5 in wp7 application ? Or we can consume only WCF application of .net framework 4.0 in window phone 7 application ? If we can consume the asp.net web service application of .net framework 3.5 then can you please tell me how to consume the asp.net web service application of .net framework 3.5?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to do that as described [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/67470/415887.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/a53ea2fb-8efd-4b97-85c7-9fa37a4184c9/).

Comment: -1 Very poor form, include at least some form of synopsis of the solution that is found in the links. A the very least use better text to describe the links. Reply in comment using @anthonywjones when done, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @anthonywjones why I must copy/past some code or text form links? Is there any need to copy something from link and past it here? In any case it will not be full solution.

Comment: We care about the quality of answers here are SO. It doesn't take a lot of effort to include at least enough text to describe what the reader will find on the end of the links.  Replacing the words "here" with the subject line of the forum posts you link to would have been sufficient for me not to have downvoted.  I still wouldn't have liked the answer but I only downvote rarely when I come across extreme examples of bad form as this answer examplifies.

Comment: @anthonywjones where is your High quality answer?

Comment: @anthonywjones and can you explain why is my "Low quality answer" has been marked as right?

Comment: Because your links clearly led Shailesh to a solution.  Interestingly there is no upvote to go with that acceptence.  I don't need to have a high quality answer of my own in order to spot a poor quality answer nor to gain any right to vote.  I don't like it when I get a downvote with the downvoter not making clear the reasons for the downvote and thus giving me the opportunity to make a rectification.  I offered you the same courtesy you are not required to comply if you don't want to, its all matter of opinion anyway.  The voting system is there for us to express such opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a service reference to an ASP.Net ASMX service. Just enter the url in the add service reference box. Silverlight does not support the old Web Reference proxies.